# Is rubbing, fingering or massaging your wife's anus permissible?

Tags: sex

Can you rub (with penis or hand), finger, or massage your wife's anus?
 I'm not talking about entering the penis. I know that's prohibited.

Answer (score 3):

The action in your question is permissible.

- [IslamiCity writes](http://www.islamicity.com/qa/action.lasso.asp?-db=services&-lay=Ask&-op=eq&number=32349&-format=detailpop.shtml&-find):
  *As far as playing with anus is concerned it is permissible.*
- [IslamQA writes](http://islamqa.info/en/40520):
  *With regard to simply touching the anal sphincter, there is nothing wrong with that, but it is better to avoid doing that because that may lead to something else, i.e. anal intercourse.*

But keep an eye on hygiene before doing that.

Comment: +1 for "**But keep an eye on hygiene before doing that**". Thank you for your answer.